# How Redirect to root URL when typing the path through URL address bar in angular 8?

Tags: angular

I have an angular 8 app, I want to redirect the user to the root path when user type the path directly on the address bar.

Comment: Modify your webserver rules. Which webserver are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. User can write or paste urls to the address bar or can use a fav link. In this case your angular app will be bootstrapped again (like a page reload).

What you can do:  You can set up a router. When route is unknown, then you can redirect to root or welcome:

```
path: '**', component: WelcomeComponent
or
path: '**', redirectTo: '/'
```

See: [angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your webserver to do it.  For instance, if you are using nginx, you can use the following rule

```
root LocationOfYourAppFiles;

location = / { 
  try_files index.html = 404; #Requests to root path are redirected to index.html
}

location / { 
  rewrite ^ / permanent; #Other requests are redirected to /
}
```